# R - new column in data frame calculated with a formula variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to assign a formula to a variable, and then take a data frame that contains the variables in the formula and make a new column with the result. I thought the function I could use would be model.frame but I'm not sure. Any idea how I can do this?

```
names(mydata) 
[1] "STATION_NAME" "LATITUDE"     "LONGITUDE"    "DATE"         "SNOW"         
[6] "TMAX"         "TMIN"         "PRCP"

varForm <- "(TMIN+TMAX)/2"
calcVect <- model.frame(varForm, data = mydata) Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'TMIN' not found
mydata$calcField <- calcVect Error: object 'calcVect' not found
```

Both mydata and varForm would be parameters for a user defined function I am working on. That's the reason for not just directly calculating the field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think you can do that with `within`

```
eq <- "varForm = (TMIN+TMAX)/2"

mydata <- within(mydata, eval(parse(text = eq)))
```

Comment: Thanks worked great!

varForm <- "(TMIN+TMAX)/2"
eq <- paste("varForm = ",varForm,sep="")
mydata <- within(mydata, eval(parse(text = eq)))